# Can't get cordova videoplayer to work in a ionic react environment

Tags: reactjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I get the next error message

`react_devtools_backend.js:4026 Native: tried calling VideoPlayer.play, but Cordova is not available. Make sure to include cordova.js or run in a device/simulator`

Comment: are you testing this on browser?

Comment: Yes i am testing it in google chrome by running the react app

Comment: Cordova only works in Real Mobile Device. it will not work in browser. To check this please run your project on real device.

Comment: how should I test this? I'm a bit new to this.. so should I use some kind of simulator or some kind of workaround so I can test this in my browser?

Comment: yes you can use Simulator. but some plugin only works on real devices. I think this video player will wok in simulator. Try it.

Comment: which simulator do you recommend